# Show local disk images in the JSP (images out of web context)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, controller

i did the servlet to make the images path accessible in the .JSP page

```
public void nova() {
        System.out.println("Nova Certidão");
        certidoes = new File("C:\\imagens\\").listFiles();
        List<String> paths= new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File arquivo : certidoes) {
        paths.add(arquivo.getPath());
        }
        result.include("files", caminhos);
    }
```

now in the page i have access to the files path in the disk in the arraylist files

in the jsp i have this to display the image:

```jsp
<c:forEach items="${files}" var="files">
${file} - 
<img src="/getImage/${file}" height="42" width="42"> 
<br>
</c:forEach>
```

and my getImage is this:

```
@Get("/getImage/{path}")
public void getImage(String path) {
    //here will come all the way to send the stream of the image if i receive the path
    System.out.println(path);

}
```

but its not working because it create a strange request image path:

it create:

```
/getImage/C:/imagens/image1.jpg
```

so its not working, if i manually type: /getImage/image1, i correctly display the system out, i think its not working for the file paths because the / (i think its obvious) but i have no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your images into a sub directory of Web application root.

I assume that your application root is  {web_apps}/yourapp. Under this directory, you will have a few sub-directorys such as WEB-INF, styles, images.

Put all your images into /yourapp/images/ (this folder is accessible from public).

In JSP

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/${file}" height="42" width="42" />
```

**UPDATED**

Since images are in a fixed folder that not in Web application root so we can't use the solution described above.

**Here is the right solution:**

1. Convert path of image ( absolute paht/relative path) to VALID URL variable using DES/AES encryption - The output can be Base16, Base64 encoding.
2. Convert based16, Base64 encoding path back to Path of the image in public void getImage function

   ```
   @Get("/getImage/{path}")     
   public void getImage(String path) {

       // path is in based16/Base64 encoding

       String pathOfImage = functionToConvertEncodedPathToRealPath ( path)

   }
   ```

Comment: but i cant, the images in the path that they are now work with another program.. i cant move them =\

Comment: why my servlet does not work when i use getImage/**C:/imagens/image.jpg**?

Comment: Because your {path} variable is C:/imagens/image.jpg. This is invalid value. {path} variable must not contain spaces, /, and some special characters.

Comment: Do you have image id for each image file?

Comment: Loc Ha, is there a way to create a id when i use the Paths.add and than the getImage receive the id and get in the certidoes, or in other mapped var, or HASH the path, show as link in the page, and the getImage decode the hash? is that possible? can you help me?

Comment: You can use database to store image information. Other question is all images under directly folder named "imagens"? and all image type is "jpg"? If yes, you can use image name as image id.

Comment: u throught about that, and not, the imagens directory is just for test i will have different directories and subfolders, and the worst, the images in the folder can be changed and can be added, thats why the database idea will be outdated in less than some hours... =(

i can transform C:\imagens\image.jpg (and others paths) to something like LKJS987SLKJS987HSUS98789HSUHSUSH, do the request, and revert this to the real path? i think that will do the trick ;x

Comment: Yes. You can do that but how do you convert LKJS987SLKJS987HSUS98789HSUHSUSH back to  C:\imagens\image.jpg. It must be two-way conversion.

Comment: hmmm yes i understand, i must use md5, sha or anyother thing tha can reverse it

Comment: MD5, SHA is one-way encryption. You need to use DES, AES. They are 2 way encryption.

Comment: a lot of job i think isnt it? how is this way you told me about ID by file name? since i cannot or i cant store the images path in database, if you know a way to "auto check/add" to database when somefile is added or deleted, it will be possible

Comment: Use DES OR AES to convert absolute path of image to valid url variable and convert back url variable to absolute path in 'public void getImage' is right solution for your case.

Comment: Your welcome. I already updated the answer so others can easily know the right solution.